# Crayon on Playstation Four

Tags: ps4

I have crayon all the non shiny black parts of my playstation four (it's a long story, and not important for the sake of this question). Anyway, now that it's there, I'm wondering the best way to get it off. Would it be baking soda? I tried a wet toilet paper roll and that didn't work. 
Also, does crayon on a playstation four pose that much of a risk to my disks or to the the actual drive inside of it. It's pretty worn down now, so maybe it's a non-issue. 
Two questions are best way to get it off, and risk assessment (maybe if baking soda poses more potential damage it's just better to leave it on).

Update: In terms of on-screen stuff it seems to be running fine. When I listen to it, I can hear stuff going on, but that might have always been going on I just never paid attention to it before.

Comment: Is it just on the outside of the PS4 or is it inside/near the disc tray/on the buttons/in the vents?

Comment: it's on the outermost parts, so you know how there's a face that tilts down and the actual disc space is kind of deeper in the ps4, its on the outer face, near the disc also

Comment: I'm not going to flag anything since I'm not 100% sure, but this question doesn't seem related to gaming other than the fact that the object that needs cleaning is a PS4. I'm not sure if there is a good SE site for this question.

Comment: @MageXy Maybe diy.stackexchange? I've flagged it as being off topic. Replace "PS4" with almost anything else and the question remains the same- _How do I get crayon off of something (without damaging it)?_

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is only peripherally related to the topic of video gaming, is unlikely to serve as a resource for visitors, and would be better served in another forum.

Answer (score 1):

I always used mayo to get crayon off of things. Perhaps a little safer than putting water on the PS4, and with the side effect of making your PS4 more delicious. Just put the mayo on the crayon markings and let it sit for a few minutes. Should come off clean with a rag without a lot of effort.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. You can go the heat route and either lay a piece of wax paper over the crayon and put a low-heat source on top of the paper to melt the crayon and let it soak up into the wax paper. Or, you can try soaking a rag in boiling water, ring it out (no dripping water) and lay it on the surface. After a few moments press wipe the crayon away with that rag. I would avoid steam though as that risks getting moisture inside the unit.

On the cold side, use ice or a flat ice-pack of some kind and lay it on the crayon covered surface. After a few moments the crayon will have hardened into a form where you can gently pop it off (not scraping) with something like a plastic spatula (like you would use for applying grout, etc...).

If the crayon is in the cracks, you'll probably want to go the heat route and have some toothpicks and qtips on hand.

As long as the crayon isn't inside the system though, it should't hurt anything other than asthetics.

Comment: that's what i thought. now i used baking soda on it, and that got most of it off, but there's still some and it's kind of oily, but i'm not sure if i want to do anything more, i might just leave it be

Comment: The banking soda seems like a risky idea as you may get the powder inside the unit.

Comment: yeah i think i got a little in there, do you know what might come of it, and what i should do/where i should go if i notice anything?

Comment: Short of taking the system appart you might want to try some compressed air, and really blast the hell out of it before you turn it on (in all the vents and holes, etc...).

Comment: ...then run some blast into the main air port as the system boots to help push anything through.

Comment: hmm i don't know where to get compressed air so i'm probably just going to just boot it up, it was a pretty minor amount so maybe nothing will come of it? like it was like a few tiny flecks basiclaly

Comment: also sorry if this is a dumb question, but would compressed air just shove it deeper into the system?

Comment: Well, the idea is that you removed all of the powder from outside. Then with the compressed air you do short bursts. Hmm... If you're in the U.S. you should be able to get a can at most electronics stores, and stores like Walmart. The idea is to kick it up and push it out. Yeah you may have some that's stuck in there, but it's not likely to hurt much. You just don't want it on the laser optics. If it's minor though you're probably ok. It was sounding like you may have used a lot.

Comment: i used a lot but most of it was on top or the sides, so a pretty small amount got near the vents and much much less got in

Comment: Well, then you can probably just blow in the vents once you have it on with the idea that airflow will pickup any particles you disturb and carry them out. Beyond that it's probably ok.